# Conditional Distribution of Uniform given Poisson

Tags: conditional-probability, poisson-distribution, uniform-distribution, marginal-distribution

> I am given that $N \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(1)$. Conditioned on $N = n$, let $X$ have uniform distribution over integer $n = 0,1,\ldots,n+1$.<sup>[sic]</sup> What is the marginal distribution of $X$?

I used the law of total probabilities but the result doesn't come up to a specific distribution. Is it possible it just have a probability mass function that doesn't match up to any common distributions?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course a PMF need not match any common distribution. In this case, however, you actually get a well-known distribution. Note, by the law of total probability, that $$\mathbf{P}(X=x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbf{P}(X=x\mid N=n)\mathbf{P}(N=n)=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathbf{1}_{0 \leq x \leq n+1}}{n+2} \cdot \frac{1}{n!}e^{-1}=\frac{1}{e}\sum_{n=x-1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!(n+2)}.$$ Then by writing $$\frac{1}{n!(n+2)}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!} - \frac{1}{(n+2)!},$$ check that the resulting series is telescoping and thus yields a simple expression.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: sorry but I'm getting confused about how you wrote that factorial product into difference between those factorials. wouldn't that yield a negative number?

Comment: We have
$$
\mathbb P(X=m\mid N=n) = \begin{cases}
\frac1{n+2},& 0\leqslant m\leqslant n+1\\
0,& m>n+1.
\end{cases}
$$
This complicates the computation of the distribution of $X$ by conditioning of $N$.